# Import random words in python and need suggestions

Tags: python, python-requests

```
words = requests.get("http://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/share/dict/words?view=co&content-type=text/plain").content.splitlines()
secret_word = "Levinson"     
secret_word = secret_word.lower()

length = int(len(secret_word))
hint = ""
hint_list = list()
guess = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = len(secret_word)/2
out_of_guesses = False

for i in range(length)     
    hint_list.append("_")
    i += 1
    i = 0

while guess != secret_word and not(out_of_guesses):
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        print(hint_list)
        guess = input("Enter guess :")
        guess_count += 1
        hint_list[i] = secret_word[i]
        i += 1
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True
if out_of_guesses:
    print("You loose :(")
else:
    print("You Win!!")``
```

Comment: What is your question? Also format your code properly

Comment: @Norhther suggested an edit for this

Comment: @Norhther the python identation made everything cluttered im sorry if its confusing but the code works only that i want to implement some more and get some critisism

Comment: https://gist.github.com/LEvinson2504/c59fd08f4bec5f20792593ae498a0b70   the correct code(with identation) running in python can be found here

Answer (score 0):

You can read a random word from the [Unix `words` file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_(Unix)). The words file is usually stored in `/usr/share/dict/words` or `/usr/dict/words`.